# glsl vertex shader glGetUniformLocation fails

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, vertex-shader, uniform

I want to set a uniform Vector in my Vertex Shader.

```
int loc = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "LightPos");
if (loc != -1)
{
    //do Stuff
}
```

The problem is that loc is -1 all the time. I tried it with a variable from the Fragment Shader, that actually worked. The Vertex Shader:

```
uniform vec3 LightPos;
varying vec2 UVCoord;
varying float LightIntensity;

void main()
{           
    UVCoord = gl_MultiTexCoord0.st;
    gl_Position = ftransform();
    vec3 Normal = normalize(gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal);
    LightIntensity = max(dot(normalize(vec3(0, -10, 0)), Normal), 0.0);
}
```

The Fragment Shader:

```
uniform sampler2D tex1;
varying vec2 UVCoord;
varying float LightIntensity;

void main()
{
    vec3 Color = vec3(texture2D(tex1, UVCoord));
    gl_FragColor = vec4(Color * LightIntensity, 1.0);
}
```

Does anybody have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry for the title, forgot to change it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, you misunderstood how `glGetUniformLocation (...)` and uniform location assignment in general works.

Locations are only assigned after your shaders are compiled and linked. This is a two-phase operation that effectively identifies only the ***used*** inputs and outputs between all stages of a GLSL program (vertex, fragment, geometry, tessellation). Because `LightPos` is not used in your vertex shader (or anywhere else for that matter) it is not assigned a location when your program is linked. It simply ceases to exist.

This is where the term ***active*** uniform comes from. And `glGetUniformLocation (...)` only returns the location of active uniforms.

---

> **Name**
>
> > [`glGetUniformLocation`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetUniformLocation.xml) — Returns the location of a uniform variable
>
> [...]
>
> **Description**
>
> > **glGetUniformLocation** returns an integer that represents the location of a specific uniform variable within a program object. name must be a null terminated string that contains no white space. name must be an ***active uniform*** variable name in program that is not a structure, an array of structures, or a subcomponent of a vector or a matrix. This function returns -1 if name does not correspond to an active uniform variable in program, if name starts with the reserved prefix "gl_", or if name is associated with an atomic counter or a named uniform block.

Comment: vec3(0, -10, 0) should represent LightPos, posted wrong code here.

Comment: @user3075425: Well, the other problem is you do not query uniform locations from ***shaders*** as the very first line of code in your question suggests you are trying to do - you query them from linked ***program*** objects.

Answer (score 0):

you don't actually *use* LightPos in the shader, so the optimiser didn't allocate any registers for it

the compiler is free to optimize uniforms and attribute out if they are not used